# How to Convert multiple Json object into json array in retrofit Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit

I want to display the following two team player list in recyclerview but all players in json object not jsonarray,

```
"Teams":{
       "4":{
       "Name_Full":"India",
       "Name_Short":"IND",
       "Players":{
          "3852":{
              "Position":"1",
              "Name_Full":"Rohit Sharma",
              "Iscaptain":true,
              "Batting":{
                  "Style":"RHB",
                  "Average":"47.88",
                  "Strikerate":"88.46",
                  "Runs":"7806"
               },
             "Bowling":{
             "Style":"OB",
             "Average":"64.37",
              "Economyrate":"5.21",
             "Wickets":"8"
           }
        },
        "3722":{
        "Position":"2",
        "Name_Full":"Shikhar Dhawan",
        "Batting":{
         "Style":"LHB",
         "Average":"45.36",
          "Strikerate":"93.59",
        "Runs":"5172"
      },
     "Bowling":{
     "Style":"OB",
      "Average":"0",
       "Economyrate":"0",
      "Wickets":"0"
 }
},
```

.....
}}

How to parse Multiple json object into json array in retrofit using Kotlin

Comment: Looks like a map keyed by integers.

Comment: @RyanM could you please explain little bit more or please refer any tutorial URL

Comment: If the order isn't important, define the type of the `Players` field as `Map<Integer, Player>`.  If you *do* care about order...it's more annoying and probably requires a custom type converter.